# Bootcamp both Windows 8 and Windows 7 on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, macbook, boot-camp, osx-mountain-lion

I currently have Windows 8 installed via Bootcamp 4(?) via Mountain Lion.

I'd like to also install Windows 7.

Is there a way to do multiple bootcamp's - what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that you can boot a full operating system, nativeley, from within a VHD (virtual hard disk)?

This is fully supported by Microsoft, and allows you to reboot any Windows 7 or 8 machine using the VHD file as though it was your boot disk.  Microsoft encourages this method for using their trial downloads - meaning you can now reboot and try out Windows Server 2012 or any other recent OS at native speeds, not emulated.

Here's a tutorial on building a Windows 7 bootable VHD file of your own:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-vhd-boot-demonstration.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use either Parallels or VM Fusion for adding windows 7 to your Mac.  OS Lion only allows 3 partitions, which Boot Camp use along with Mac OS!

By using Parallels (my recommendation) you can add Windows 7, which will work ALONG WITH YOUR Mac.  I.e. drag 'n' Drop. copy/paste, etc.,!

With Boot Camp, you can only use EITHER Mac OS OR WINDOWS!

Comment: -1 With parallels, you cannot boot Windows. Also, you didn’t answer the asker’s original question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define your needs a bit better? Why do you need 7 & 8? Can you get away with running 7 as a virtual machine in? Windows offers [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) as a free virtualization solution.

Here is what I would try to do:

1. You might have to go around Boot Camp Assistant
2. Use disk Utility to Shrink/partition the drive into 2(the second is the combined windows space)
3. Put Windows 7 Disk in drive
4. Reboot and hold Option during startup, select DVD
5. During Install Setup it will ask you to select drive to install to. It will make you to delete,format and set the size of the Destination Partition. Split the space for 7 & 8 as needed. Only format the space needed for 7, leave the rest for 8 to handle during its install
6. finish 7 install
7. insert 8 disk and reboot holding option again. Select 8 dvd to boot.
8. During Install Setup be sure to choose custom install(don't upgrade 7 install!)
9. Format remaining free space into Destination Partition
10. Be sure to download Boot Camp Software 5 from Apple and install on both 7 & 8